# How to stop files from magically becoming Read Only?

Tags: office-365, error, excel, read-only, save

I've had this document open since 8:00 AM when I came in to work.  I occasionally make changes and save the document.  Just now I tried to do the same but I get the following message:

[image]

I'm getting *very* tired of this.  It happens a few times a week.  Today it's happened twice on the same document in 3 hours.  When it happens I have to save it as a copy, delete the original and rename the copy.

I'm 99% positive nobody else is using the document (it's on my personal site, not the main company site)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable check-out on the library. So you could control the lock by yourself, as in check-out when you are modifying the document, and check it in once you are done.